# Dynamic SQL Temp table error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've found a strage compiling bug in MS SQL.

So let's say we have a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test 
@FirstPart bit 
AS 


BEGIN
if @FirstPart = 1 begin
Declare @SQL varchar(max)
    set @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #Test ADD Column2 varchar(100)'
    exec(@SQL)

    set @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #Test ADD Column3 varchar(100)'
    exec(@SQL)
end else        
        SELECT Column1, Column2,Column3 FROM #Test
END
```

Then in an other sesion we do this

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (Column1 varchar(100))    
exec Test 1
```

Normally this will execute the 2 alter table statements with  no problem but this query runs with errors

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 15
Invalid column name 'Column2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 15
Invalid column name 'Column3'.
```

Any ideas?

EDIT :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Test 

AS 


BEGIN



--if @FirstPart = 1 begin
Declare @SQL varchar(max)
    set @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #Test ADD Column2 varchar(100)'
    exec(@SQL)

    set @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #Test ADD Column3 varchar(100)'
    exec(@SQL)
--end else      
        SELECT Column1, Column2,Column3 FROM #Test
END
```

Comment: when `@FirstPart <> 1` you will get that error also i don't see the need of dynamic query here

Comment: I notice if you comment out the "else" portion of the proc, you don't get the error on execution.  This suggests to me that when the proc is called, both sides of the if are evaluated for errors, rather than only the side that is going to get executed.   SQL is known to work like this, I believe.

Comment: @NoDisplayName this is just a small example, my initial query has an unknown number of columns, so I need dynamic sql. Also the way I execute the procedure is with the value 1 so there is no way it could go to the case <> 1

Comment: @TabAlleman yes indeed this is the problem, but it looks like an annoying bug. Why would be a certain part of the code throw error if that code is not even executed.

Comment: I think it has to do with the way SQL has to create an execution plan.  The execution plan doesn't know what parts of the code are going to get executed.  A workaround would be to use dynamic sql for the "else" query as well.

Comment: Maybe you could look at the whole process. It seems that a procedure trying to execute against an unknown structure kind of goes against the concept of data manipulation. This has the "one procedure to rule them all" kind of feel which is always fraught with lots of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Like you already noticed, query plan is made for the whole procedure. Most likely because it would take a lot more time to try to analyse the code (and in worst case even the data) to figure out what parts of the code will actually be executed and what will not.

If you have this kind of features, you'll probably should separate them into 2 different procedures anyhow. That would also help also in creating better plan when the plan is made with the parameter values actually used in the execution of that part -- assuming you actually have more functionality in your procedure.

Comment: i've already did that ( separate them ) but I was just wondering why does the SQL run like that. Cuz even if you remove the IF and run ( check the edit I made on the post it still runs with errors)

Comment: Yes the plan is made before the procedure execution starts. If you run the alter statements normally, without using the exec, then it will work. If I remember correctly the plan from that point onwards is only created later on, since alter tables cause recompile to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround i found is `select` should also be present in dynamic query.

```
create  PROCEDURE Test @FirstPart BIT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)

      SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #Test ADD Column2 varchar(100)'

      EXEC(@SQL)

      SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #Test ADD Column3 varchar(100)'

      EXEC(@SQL)

      EXEC('SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3 FROM  #Test') -- Dynamic query
  END

CREATE TABLE #Test
  (Column1 VARCHAR(100))

EXEC Test 1
```